# Finding the second last occurence of a string in Regex

Tags: regex

I have to find an invoice number with ten digits in the text of an invoice in a scanning and capture application.

The problem is, there could be phone numbers and fax numbers with 10 digits as well, but in most invoices the invoice number is the second last number (there is an order number with ten digits after it). I've tried different approaches but I cannot work out how to get the second last occurrence of a match?

I start with `[0-9]{10}` which finds all of the ten digit numbers. Then I put some parentheses around, which returns the groups. So, then I thought

```
(?:[0-9]{10}){2}[0-9]{10}
```

would have given me the third occurrence, but it returns nothing. And in any case, I would need something like `count-1` to find the second last group, if that makes sense?

TestString:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor >congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar 0234567890 ultricies, purus >lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra >1111111111  imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus. Pellentesque >habitant morbi tristique senectus et 1234567890  netus et malesuada fames ac >turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. 1234567890 Mauris et orci. Aenean nec 1234767890 lorem.

and I want to extract the 1234567890 before 'Mauris'.

Comment: Can you add a test string to your question please?

Comment: @Matt, ok, have added one

Comment: `sed -re 's/.*([0-9]{10}).*[0-9]{10}.*/\1/'` works on the example. You really must specify in what application / language you want to use the regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for your test string.

```
.*(\d{10}).*\d{10}.*$
```

The main trick is to include the last 10 digit string as part of your regex, and then use a capturing group on the 10 digit string before it. You might have to play with the regex a bit if there are variations on your test string.

Comment: Works perfect. Only issue I've just come across is that on some invoices, the capture engine adds a carriage return. But I can handle that in the application itself. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try

```
/.*(\b\d{10}\b).*\b\d{10}\b/
```